# Is possible to avoid recurrence in a method call in php when the object added to the list is the same?

Tags: php, algorithm, object, recursion, tree

I have a method in a class that receives an element and put it into a list, the class has another method that prints that list like a Tree, but the problem is when you add the same object as a child it converts in an infinite cycle. How can avoid this? How can I check if the object to be added to the Tree is the same reference?

```
class Tree {
   public $nodeName;
   public $elements;
   public function addElement( $element )
   {
      if (!is_array( $this->elements )) $this->elements = array();
      array_push( $this->elements, $element );
   }
   public function print()
   {
      echo $this->nodeName;
      foreach ($this->elements as $element) {
          $element->print();
      }
   }
}

$t = new Tree();
$t->addElement( $t );
$t->print();
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should also need to check that a grandparent node isn't also added as a child node.  There are all sorts of ways that a loop can be created when creating a tree structure.

Comment: @NigelRen How can I check this in PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to check if the same object is been added you can use: `if ($element === $this)`.

Formal documataion is here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

But, you should also consider a case which in the loop is cause by several levels (as root been added to leaf for example). This need to be avoid because of the fact that tree definition is graph without circles...

In order to sove that I would add a function name `exist($elementToFind)` in the tree class with the following algorithm:

1. If `$elementToFind === $this` return true.
2. foreach `$this->elements`: if `$element->exist($elememtToFind)` return true.

Now all you need is to call the `exist` method at the begin of the `addElement` function and if its return true then throw error.

Notice, that is will not solve a case of adding tree b with leaf a to tree a - so you may check also all the `elements` under the new element you want to add. You can do so by adding 3 step:

3. Foreach `$elementToFind->$elememts as $elem`: if `$elem->exist($this)` is true -> return true

Comment: Hi, thanks by your answer, I tryed something like your answer but I clone the object: `if ($element === $this) return clone $element;`, but I get the same recurrence.

Comment: @CristianJimenez Did my post answer you? What did you mean by same recurrence? Try do `$x = clone $element` in the if-statement and then check `if ($this === $x`